# Mongotemplate: How to convert result field to custom Java Type?

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

```
// collection: test
{
  ...
  Datetime: 43665.384931
  ...
}
```

```java
public Class POJO {
  @Field("ID")
  private String id;

  @Field("Datetime")
  private Date datetime; // Where can I implement a converter to cast double value from mongo to Java type Date here?
}
```

```java
mongoTemplate.findOne(new Query(), POJO.class, "test")
```

Where can I implement a converter to cast double value from mongo to Java type Date here?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to give `@Field(targetType = FieldType.INT64)` of the upcoming Spring Data MongoDB 2.2 release a try. It allows to pass on type information to the conversion subsystem using the `ConversionService` to perform the required transformations.

```java
class Pojo {

  String id;
  @Field(targetType = FieldType.INT64) Date date;
}
```

At the time of writing there are only converters registered for a `Date -> String` conversion, but none for `Date -> Long`, so you'll need to register the converter as well.

```java
((GenericConversionService) mongoTemplate.getConverter().getConversionService())
  .addConverter(new Converter<Date, Long>() {
    @Override
    public Long convert(Date source) {
      return source.getTime();
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Registering a `MongoCustomConversions` bean works for me.